# ISC WASP fixed block interval

Tags: smart-contract, wasp

is there way to set a fixed block interval in WASM based chains?

e.g. call a `tick()` function every 10 seconds.

in particular, i need a way of calculating elapsed time since X

````
let tick = 0;

func1 {
   tick = now();
}

func2 { 
  if now() > tick + 10 {
      do xyz
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

Usually, smart contracts require an external trigger whatever VM it may be or you might run out of funds pretty quick if left unchecked.

Comment: is this because of the on-tangle root commitment fees?

Comment: No. That's how every decentralised network works. This was long solved on Ethereum and every network follows it since.